# count distincts including null

Tags: sql, distinct

I have this problem and i cant resolve :

The table "habitacions" records, for each room, the time the guests must be awoken at (columns "hora" and "minut"). If the time is a null value, the guests must not be awoken. Give a SQL sentence returning the number of different hours (ignoring column "minut") someone must be awoken at. Willing not to be awoken is considered as a new different hour.

```
CREATE TABLE vigilants(
nom VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY key,
edat integer);

CREATE TABLE rondes(
hora INTEGER,
planta INTEGER,
vigilant VARCHAR(20) REFERENCES vigilants,
PRIMARY KEY(hora, planta));

CREATE TABLE habitacions(
num INTEGER,
planta INTEGER,
places INTEGER,
hora INTEGER,
minut INTEGER,
PRIMARY KEY(num, planta),
FOREIGN KEY(hora, planta) REFERENCES rondes);`
```

with this restrictions:
    Try to minimize the number of subqueries you need to solve the query. Furthermore, you are not allowed to use the following constructions:
    - SELECT in the FROM or SELECT. You are allowed to have subqueries (SELECT in the WHERE or HAVING)
    - Combinations of aggregation functions such as COUNT (COUNT. ..)), SUM (COUNT. ..))         and the like.
    - UNION if you can avoid it.
    - Non-standard functions (such as NVL)
    - CASE

example: with this inserts:

```
INSERT INTO vigilants(nom, edat) VALUES ('Mulder', 32);
INSERT INTO vigilants(nom, edat) VALUES ('Scully', 30);

INSERT INTO rondes(hora, planta, vigilant) VALUES (7, 1, 'Mulder');
INSERT INTO rondes(hora, planta, vigilant) VALUES (8, 1, 'Mulder');
INSERT INTO rondes(hora, planta, vigilant) VALUES (7, 2, 'Mulder');

INSERT INTO habitacions(num, planta, places, hora, minut) VALUES (1, 1, 1, 7, 30);
INSERT INTO habitacions(num, planta, places, hora, minut) VALUES (5, 1, 1, 7, 30);
INSERT INTO habitacions(num, planta, places, hora, minut) VALUES (2, 1, 1, 8, 30);
INSERT INTO habitacions(num, planta, places, hora, minut) VALUES (3, 1, 1, null, null);
INSERT INTO habitacions(num, planta, places, hora, minut) VALUES (4, 1, 1, null, null);
INSERT INTO habitacions(num, planta, places, hora, minut) VALUES (1, 2, 1, null, null);
```

result is 3 :) (7,8 and null)

Ty a lot

Comment: You should be explicit if this is a homework assignment.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Counting null values as unique value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15040602/counting-null-values-as-unique-value)

Comment: Yes is homework assignment :), I use oracle

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  you can use the `coalesce()` function with `count(distinct)`.

So, something like the following is allowed:

```
select count(distinct coalesce(hour, -1))
```

It replaces NULL values with the -1, which is not a valid value.  This should have the effect that you are looking for.

Comment: ty for answer but as I saied I cant use Non-standard functions (such as NVL) and I think coalesce is the same :P

Comment: @user2103217 . . . `COALESCE()` is ANSI standard, so it certainly doesn't seem "non-standard" to the rest of the world.  You can also use a `case` statement, to get the same effect.

Comment: `COALESCE()` function is in SQL (ANSI/ISO) standard.