# Off by one difference between count distinct in sqldf() and tidy code

Tags: r, sqlite, tidyr, sqldf

I am trying to count the number of distinct names from a dataset in R using the sqldf package, and wanted to check my answer using tidy. I got a slightly different answer, and couldn't figure out what caused it. Here's my code:

```
mayors <- read_csv(file="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jmontgomery/jmontgomery.github.io/master/PDS/Datasets/Mayors.csv")
mayorsDF <- as.data.frame(mayors)

library(sqldf)
sqldf("select count(distinct FullName) from mayorsDF") # gives me 1406

allNamesDF <- sqldf("select distinct FullName from mayorsDF")
length(allNamesDF$FullName) # gives me 1407

library(tidyverse)
mayors %>% 
    select("FullName") %>%
    unique() %>%
    count() # gives me 1407
```

What am I missing? I'm new to the sqldf package, but not new to SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL does not count nulls as unique values in `count distinct`, and you have nulls in your data.

```r
sqldf::sqldf("select count(*) as n from mayorsDF where FullName is null")
#    n
# 1 36
allNamesDF <- sqldf::sqldf("select distinct FullName from mayorsDF")
anyNA(allNamesDF)
# [1] TRUE
sum(is.na(allNamesDF))
# [1] 1
length(unique(allNamesDF[!is.na(allNamesDF)]))
# [1] 1406
```

Related: [Counting null values as unique value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15040602)